# Creating Ajax Request

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, get

I'm fairly new to AJAX, so I was having a little trouble getting started.

Basically, I want to make an AJAX request using the `GET` option and have a URL such as `admin/something.php?id=1&that=33` be sent to the backend which will perform my PHP functions.

How am I going to generate my data using `attr` like `$(this).attr('id')` which is basically just grabbing DIV.ID information and such?

EDIT:
How could I integrate it into this `sortable` function?

```
$( ".heriyah" ).sortable({
    handle : '.handle',
    connectWith: ".heriyah",
    revert: "invalid",
    update: function(event, ui){
    if(($(ui.sender).attr('id') == undefined)&&($(this).attr('id') == ui.item.parent().attr('id'))){
         alert('UPDATE ' + $(this).attr('id') + ' ' + (ui.item.index()+1) + ' ' + $(ui.item).text()); 
    }
},
```

Comment: In which case you may find the [detailed AJAX documentation a good start](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax), in particular the [`jQuery.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use jquery to generate ajax request. See documentation [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Example code might look like this:

```
var request = $.ajax({
                    url: "something.php",
                    type: "GET",
                    data: {id:1,that:33} ,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
                });

 request.done(function (data) {
     //Put complete code here
 });

 request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
      alert("Request failed: " + textStatus);
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery does the trick very simple:

$.ajax({

```
    url: "admin/something.php?id=1&that=33",
    context: document.body,
    success: function(data){
        // display the return from something.php
        $("#myresult").html(data);
    }
```

});